# Can't remove plot mark from 3d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying for the first time to do a 3 dimensional plot using pgfplots. I'd like to remove the blue marks in the graph but I can't understand how. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
surf, xmax=3,xmin=-3,ymax=3,ymin=-3,
    %view={0}{90},
    shader=interp,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    colorbar,
    meta min=0,
    meta max=10] \addplot3{(0.01014-0.001554*x^2+0.00293*y^2+0.002785*x^2*y^2+0.001167*x^4)/(0.009553)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

This is my result:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile, because it is not complete and because of errors. If it could compile, it would not produce the picture you show with marks.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-3, xmax=3,
ymin=-3, ymax=3,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
colorbar,
point meta min=0,
point meta max=10,
]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp]{(0.01014-0.001554*x^2+0.00293*y^2+0.002785*x^2*y^2+0.001167*x^4)/(0.009553)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]